# Is it possible to increase the size of the text boxes in a Smart Capture Form in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

Just wondering if there's any css for this that can be used to increase the text box sizes on certain fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is YES!

Basically a **every Smart Capture** form created by the MC platform will be assigned with a **unique ID**. And this ID is used across all the CSS ans well to identify the form.
[image]

Now using the basic CSS we must find the required class [which will be automatically created by the platform] **But be cautious NOT to change any of the existing Class name, doing so might cause the entered NOT stored to DE**

Consider the below two examples,

1. Increasing the input field width.

   **Before** 
   [image]

   **After** 
   [image]
2. Increasing the font-size and font color.

   **Code** 
   [image]

   **Output**
   [image]

These are just a simple example, the one with good HTML/CSS knowledge can create Beautiful looking UIs!

Comment: Thanks so much - this is perfect.